# How do I include a stored value in a css path with Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

For example:

```
<tr>
  <td>storeEval</td>
  <td>a_string</td>
  <td>my_var</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
  <td>css=#some_id[some_value='<my_var>']</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css=#some_id[some_value='${my_var}']